# Stuck in a simple trigonometric problem

Tags: trigonometry

I was doing my assignment, when I got to this equation:

$\ sin (10\pi (x+0,01))$= $\ 2 sin(10\pi x)$

I tried solving it by using a program to draw out the graph, but the value I got ($\approx 0,565 $) wasn't a solution. 
I'm having problems understanding trigonometry, also all kind of help is welcomed.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try something like $\sin(10\pi(x+0.01)) \approx 0.1\pi \sin(10\pi x) + \cos(10\pi x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is $$\sin(10\pi x)\cos(\frac{\pi}{10})+\cos(10\pi x)\sin(\frac{\pi}{10})-2\sin(10\pi x)=0$$ after the Addition formula
and then use that $$\sin(10\pi x)=2\,{\frac {\tan \left( 5\,\pi\,x \right) }{1+ \left( \tan \left( 5\,
\pi\,x \right)  \right) ^{2}}}
$$
and
$$\cos(10\pi x)={\frac {1- \left( \tan \left( 5\,\pi\,x \right)  \right) ^{2}}{1+
 \left( \tan \left( 5\,\pi\,x \right)  \right) ^{2}}}
$$
and set $$t=\tan(5\pi x)$$

Comment: Thank you for your clear and detailed answer! I managed to get till the first row but then I didn't see any connection. I wouldn't have noticed, that 10πx could be viewed as 2 α if you don't point it out.

Comment: i have used $\sin(x+y)=\sin(x)\cos(y)+\cos(x)\sin(y)$

Comment: first yes, but then sin(2α) = (2tg α ) / (1 + tg^2 α) which I didn't notice was possible to use here. Thanks again!

Comment: if you make this substituion you will get an equation in $t$ since  $\sin(\pi/10)$ and $\cos(\pi/10)$ are constants